# Bash shell scripting syntactical issues: Target is not a directory?

Tags: bash, shell

I am attempting to copy a file to a bunch of folders present in a directory. The folders have been saved in `propagation.txt` and are like:

```
sfproject/folder1
sfproject/folder2
```

The code I am attempting to run is :

```
for x in `cat propagation.txt`
do cp php.ini $x ; echo "Copied php.ini to $x"
done
echo "Finished";
```

However, it states that:

```
cp : 'target: 'propagation.txt' is not a text'
```

This is what propagation.txt consists of:

```
sfproject/apps/backend/modules/users/lib
sfproject/apps/backend/templates
sfproject/apps/frontend/config
sfproject/apps/frontend/lib
sfproject/apps/frontend/modules/EdboostSatGuide/actions
sfproject/apps/frontend/modules/EdboostSatGuide/templates
sfproject/apps/frontend/modules/dashboard/actions
sfproject/apps/frontend/modules/dashboard/templates
sfproject/apps/frontend/modules/quizzes/actions
sfproject/apps/frontend/modules/quizzes/templates
sfproject/apps/frontend/templates
sfproject/cache/frontend/prod/config
```

Comment: "is not a text"? Neither me, nor google are not aware of such cp output. Is it correct one? Can you move echo before cp and show log. And run `which cp` on your system

Comment: consider editing your question to include 2-3 line sample of what is in propagation.txt. Good luck.

Comment: You title says "target is not a directory"; your question says "target is not a text".  Is the title correct and the question wrong?  If so, it makes sense; if not, then the 'is not a text' error message makes no sense (is non-sense, or possibly even nonsense).  There are still some puzzles to resolve, but at least the inconsistency between title and question would be clear if it should read 'is not a directory'.

Answer (score 10):

"Target is not a directory" is a `cp` error. It happens when you have three or more arguments, and the last argument is an existing filesystem object that isn't a directory!

Of course

cp a b

works if `b` is a regular file, and not a directory. `b` is simply replaced with `a`. But

cp a b c

means make a copy of `a` and `b` inside directory `c`.

It's not clear how this problem could happen in your `cp php.ini $x`, because the loop variable `$x` is iterating over the results of a `cat ...` process substitution. The process substitution undergoes word splitting and the split pieces are assigned to `x` one by one.  For your `cp` to end up with three or more arguments, `$x` would have to somehow expand into two arguments.

Post the actual verbatim code that is failing and some sample data.

On a related note, if you do have spaces in some of the path names, it will be best to put them on separate lines in `propagation.txt` and then process it like this:

```
# read dir names one by one and copy php.ini into them ...
while read dir ; do
    cp php.ini "$dir"
    # ...
done < propagation.txt  # ... getting the names from propagation.txt
```

Comment: If you encounter this error in command with parameter, like `cp -a a b`, check that the minus preceding the parameter is actually a minus and not some kind of unicode dash.

Answer (score 1):

It should work, change "do cp php.ini" to "do echo cp php.ini" and see what you get.

Comment: i did not get anything besides:
cp php.ini cat propagation.txt
this probably means it is refusing to read the contents of propagation.txt since it only spits that line out once

Comment: I used your propagation.txt file content and change the script to : for x in `cat propagation.txt` ; do echo '(' cp php.ini $x ')' ; echo "Copied php.ini to $x" ; done; echo "Finished"; it prints out what is sent to the cp command. See if you get what you expected

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to @pizza, I'm pretty sure your actual script is not what's in the question.  I suspect you may have the wrong kind of quotes around `cat propagation.txt`, i.e.

```
for x in 'cat propagation.txt' ; do cp php.ini $x ; echo "Copied php.ini to $x" ; done; echo "Finished";
```

instead of

```
for x in `cat propagation.txt` ; do cp php.ini $x ; echo "Copied php.ini to $x" ; done; echo "Finished";
```

...or possibly some sort of "smart quote" or the like.  I'll recommend using `$()` instead of backquotes; they do basically the same thing, but the syntax is cleaner if you're doing complex things and they're *much harder to mistake for something else*.  So try this:

```
for x in $(cat propagation.txt) ; do cp php.ini $x ; echo "Copied php.ini to $x" ; done; echo "Finished"
```